# JavaScript function to search elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, search

I have a search bar, and an unordered list.

```
<input onkeyup="Cautare()" type='text' id='userInput' placeholder='Cautare...'>
<button class="Buton" id='Trimitere' onclick="TrimitereWikipedia()">Cautare Wikipedia</button>
<br />
<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="Istoria_Opticii.html">ISTORIA OPTICII</a></li>
  <li><a href="Principiile_Opticii_Geometrice.html">PRINCIPIILE OPTICII GEOMETRICE</a></li>
</ul>
```

With this JS function (Cautare()):

```
function Cautare() {
var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
input = document.getElementById("userInput");
filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}}
```

So this function basically searches what's inside the `<a>` tags from `<li>`
I wanted to make this script kinda search what's inside of the content by doing this:

- add `<p style="display: none">content</p>`: so the word 'content' would be another 'keyword' which you can't see;
- declaring `p` variable in the function
- `p = li[i].getElementsByTagName("p")[0];`, under `a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];`
- add in the if statement: `|| p.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1`

So when I put the word "content" in the search bar the first list item should appear, but nothing is happening and in fact all of this breaks the function.

How could I edit the function so I can finish what I want to do? I am not very experienced with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1: data attributes**

You can use `data attributes` to store that additional keyword. Something like `<a href="Istoria_Opticii.html" data-keyword="content">` and then you can get that keyword using `element.dataset.keyword`.

Note that if you want to select those `a` elements, and you hold reference to their parent, all you need to do is ask for `firstChild`. And even better, just select them right away using `#myUL > li > a` pattern combined with `querySelectorAll`.

Also note that you should use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` if you need to get only the text.

```js
function Cautare() {
  const inputValue = document.getElementById('userInput').value.toUpperCase();
  const items = [...document.querySelectorAll('#myUL > li > a')];

  items.forEach(item => {
    if (item.textContent.toUpperCase().includes(inputValue) ||
        item.dataset.keyword.toUpperCase().includes(inputValue)) {
      item.parentElement.style.display = '';
    } else {
      item.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<input onkeyup="Cautare()" type='text' id='userInput' placeholder='Cautare...'>
<!-- <button class="Buton" id='Trimitere' onclick="TrimitereWikipedia()">Cautare Wikipedia</button> -->
<br />
<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="Istoria_Opticii.html" data-keyword="content">ISTORIA OPTICII</a></li>
  <li><a href="Principiile_Opticii_Geometrice.html" data-keyword="somethingElse">PRINCIPIILE OPTICII GEOMETRICE</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now, if you start typing word `content` the first `li` element will stay visible (second will stay visible if you start typing `somethingelse`).

**Option 2: hidden elements**

You can use hidden elements the way you have described if you want to. Snippet below shows how, using the hidden `p` element the way that you have mentioned.

```js
function Cautare() {
  const inputValue = document.getElementById('userInput').value.toUpperCase();
  const items = [...document.querySelectorAll('#myUL > li')];

  items.forEach(item => {
    const aElem = item.querySelector('a');
    const pElem = item.querySelector('p');

    if (aElem.textContent.toUpperCase().includes(inputValue) ||
        pElem.textContent.toUpperCase().includes(inputValue)) {
      item.style.display = '';
    } else {
      item.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<input onkeyup="Cautare()" type='text' id='userInput' placeholder='Cautare...'>
<!-- <button class="Buton" id='Trimitere' onclick="TrimitereWikipedia()">Cautare Wikipedia</button> -->
<br />

<ul id="myUL">
  <li>
    <p style="display: none">content</p>
    <a href="Istoria_Opticii.html">ISTORIA OPTICII</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p style="display: none">somethingElse</p>
    <a href="Principiile_Opticii_Geometrice.html">PRINCIPIILE OPTICII GEOMETRICE</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Option 3: Map/WeakMap**

Another option would be to create a map that would hold individual `li` elements as keys and keywords associated with them as values.

```js
function Cautare() {
  const inputValue = document.getElementById('userInput').value.toUpperCase();
  const items = [...document.querySelectorAll('li')];
  const keywords = new WeakMap([[items[0], 'content'], [items[1], 'somethingElse']]);

  items.forEach(item => {
    if (item.firstChild.textContent.toUpperCase().includes(inputValue) ||
        keywords.get(item).toUpperCase().includes(inputValue)) {
      item.style.display = '';
    } else {
      item.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<input onkeyup="Cautare()" type='text' id='userInput' placeholder='Cautare...'>
<!-- <button class="Buton" id='Trimitere' onclick="TrimitereWikipedia()">Cautare Wikipedia</button> -->
<br />

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="Istoria_Opticii.html">ISTORIA OPTICII</a></li>
  <li><a href="Principiile_Opticii_Geometrice.html">PRINCIPIILE OPTICII GEOMETRICE</a></li>
</ul>
```

This approach can be simplified even more if you store both keyword and text content of a given item in the map. In such case, you need to check only one condition.

```js
function Cautare() {
  const inputValue = document.getElementById('userInput').value.toUpperCase();
  const items = [...document.querySelectorAll('li')];
  const keywords = new WeakMap([[items[0], 'content, ISTORIA OPTICII'],
                                [items[1], 'somethingElse, PRINCIPIILE OPTICII GEOMETRICE']]);
                                
  items.forEach(item => {
    keywords.get(item).toUpperCase().includes(inputValue) ?
      item.style.display = '' :
      item.style.display = 'none';
  });
}
```

```html
<input onkeyup="Cautare()" type='text' id='userInput' placeholder='Cautare...'>
<!-- <button class="Buton" id='Trimitere' onclick="TrimitereWikipedia()">Cautare Wikipedia</button> -->
<br />

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="Istoria_Opticii.html">ISTORIA OPTICII</a></li>
  <li><a href="Principiile_Opticii_Geometrice.html">PRINCIPIILE OPTICII GEOMETRICE</a></li>
</ul>
```